# Calling a method in my PreferenceActivity Activity form another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, preferenceactivity

Hi and thanks for your help,

I have the following situation.

In my App I use PreferenceActivity to show and allow changes of settings, let's call it **PreferenceActivity A**.

If the user selects one particular preference a new Activity is launched, let's call it **Activity B** (A is not destroyed).

**What I need to do is to call a method of PreferenceActivity A form inside Activity B.**

*Please note: that the method in PreferenceActivity A cannot be static.*

Any help very much appreciated.

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

This is how Activty B is launched:
When the user taps on the correspondent item in the PreferenceActivity A screen the intent is triggered.

```
 <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="addstocks"
        android:summary="Click here to add stocks"
        android:title="Add stocks" >
        <intent
            android:targetClass="com.stocktickerwidget.QuotesActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.stocktickerwidget" />
```

Comment: Do you need to pass arguments to the method, and does the method need to return something to the caller? What is the goal of calling this method (i.e. is it just so that the user sees something different when they return to Activity A)?

Comment: @Karakuri nothing needs to be passed. Activity A will change appearance because of invocation of that method.

Comment: In that case I recommend using `startActivityForResult()`, passing back a result, and changing the appearance in `onActivityResult()`. You could potentially use a Handler and Messenger, but I think the first is easier and more clear.

Comment: @Karakuri sorry, I cannot use `startActivityForResult()` because Activity B is launched in the way you can see in the edited code.

Comment: yes, you can. set an OnPreferenceClickListener on that preference and start ActivityB yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting the activity like that, manually set an OnPreferenceClickListener on the preference and use `startActivityForResult()`.

```
private static final int RESUEST_CODE = 1;
protected void onCreate() {
    /* ... */
    Preference pref = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("addstocks");
    pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference() {
            if (preference.getKey().equals("addstocks") {
                startActivityB();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void startActivityB() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```